# How can I move a marker given an array of positions?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typescript, ionic2, marker

I am trying to move a marker to positions stored into an array.

```
            let vehicule_assigne_geo = { lat: 45.495252, lng: -73.605798 };
            var image = "img/Sedan-52.png";
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: vehicule_assigne_geo,
                        map: self.map,
                        draggable: false,
                        icon: image,
                        title: 'Your taxi'
            });
            //self.tabmarkers is my array of positions
            //positions have this format: var LatLng = { lat:steps[c].lat_lngs[i].lat() , lng: steps[c].lat_lngs[i].lng() };
            for(var i=0;i<self.tabmarkers.length;i++){
                marker.setPosition(self.tabmarkers[i])    
            }
```

I can see the marker at the last position of the array.I tried to put o timeout like this

```
setTimeout(3000)
```

just after setting the position.But this doesn't change the result.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like Google Maps' [`Marker animations with setTimeout()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) example:

The trick is to multiply the timeout value. Or you may use the setInterval() method. 
As you did not gave your entire code, you will need something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < self.tabmarkers.length; i++){
    moveMarkerWithTimeout(self.tabmarkers[i], i * 1000);        
};
function moveMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       marker.setPosition(position);
    }, timeout);
}
```

Haven't tested but it should work.